# google search result : webpage ranking order

Tags: google, search-engines, pagerank, seo

[image: from google]

I want to know when I typed - cheapest mobile phone in india. I get this website title inside the red box first (The title is not relevant to my typed phrase), whereas which is relevant, inside the blue box is positioned below.

Answer (score 3):

You're not searching for a phrase, if you put it into quotes and search google for "cheapest mobile phone in india" you get different results. The site in blue is actually on top when searching for the phrase.

If you just type into the search box google will look for websites that have most of the words you typed, the more the better. As John said google considers cheap and cheapest to be equivalent. Only when you put the phrase into quotes google will search for the exact phrase.

Answer (score 1):

That title *is* relevant to your typed phrase. "Relevant" does not mean "exact match". Google knows that "cheapest" is another form of "cheap" so it considers that phrase to be a good match for your search query. This also applies to past tense (*ed) and plural words (*s).

Comment: Thanks John, However, don't you think so that, there are more searches associated with cheap mobile rather than cheapest and so, cheapest get replaced by cheap. Please do post your opinion about my crazy thought :)